# Vercel/NextJS: How to access serverless functions from frontend during local development?

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js, serverless, vercel

My React/NextJS front end has a Button component that fetches data via a serverless function when the button is clicked. I want to test this functionality during local development with the Vercel dev/CLI tools. I am getting a 404 result when attempting to access my lambda functions. Here are the approximate steps that I've gone through so far:

1. Create `package.json` with a dev script:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "yarn codegen && next --hostname=0.0.0.0 --port=3001",
}
...
```

2. Link to deployed vercel project
3. Create `vercel.json` to specify builds and routes:

```
...
    "builds": [
        { "src": "*.html", "use": "@now/static" },
        { "src": "pages/api/*.py", "use": "@now/python" },
    ],
    "routes": [
        { "src": "/api/validate", "dest": "/pages/api/validate.py" }
    ]
...
```

4. Create my test Lambda function (in python):

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from datetime import datetime

class handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

  def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).encode())
    return
```

5. Create my Button component:

```
...
    <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        onClick={() => {
            fetch('api/validate')
                .then(response => { console.log(response)
                    response.json() })
                .then(data => console.log(data))
        }}
    >
        Generate sample dataset
    </Button>
...
```

6. Run `vercel dev`
7. Access website at `localhost:3001` (next dev server address)
8. Click button

---

**Result**:

I'm receiving a `404` response

Note: I can access the lambda function from `localhost:3000/pages/api/validate.py` (vercel dev server address). This appears to manually kickstart the lambda function build and serve process. I thought that it should have been built and served already from the `vercel.json` specification and be available at `localhost:3001/api/validate`. This seems to agree with the [Vercel documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#introduction/configuration-reference).

Note 2: Next dev/CLI tools build and serve javascript/typescript files just fine. I'm using python and Go functions as well, which are supported by Vercel dev/CLI but not Next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to use `vercel dev` instead of `next dev` or `yarn dev`, and to use an environment variable in a `.env` file that points to the function url. This env variable should be prepended with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` so that it is registered by next.js and passed to `process.env` during the build process.

```
# .env
NEXT_PUBLIC_FUNCTIONS_BASE_URL="http://localhost:3000" # 3000 is vercel port
```

```js
# component.js
...
fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FUNCTIONS_BASE_URL + '/api/function-name')
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the port from `vercel dev` to the upstream CLI, in this case `next dev`.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "yarn codegen && next dev --port=$PORT",
  }
}
```

Now when you run `vercel dev`, the ephemeral port will be proxied from the dev server.

You can also remove `vercel.json` if you rename `/pages/api` to `/api`.